# Badly Hung Door

Tags: door-frame

When opening this door more than 90 degrees or so, it hits the floor, which I checked, it's level. 
It seems the doors was not hung properly.

[image]

2 choices, when open as far as it will go, just produce a line 1/4" off the floor and shave off that much wood. Other choice is to unscrew hinges and pull the top hinge in a bit, and middle hinge half as much.

What is the better choice? I've lived with this a very long time, but it's time to fix this.

Comment: Would you prefer having a larger gap under the door when it's closed, or reinstalling the door/jamb? Is the jamb plumb (you can check with a level, or a plumb line)?

Comment: Is the floor level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two minutes to mark the bottom of the door whether it be a 1/4" mark or a 1/2" mark up from the floor, 10 minutes to pull the door pins, 10 minutes to set up a workbench of a sort, and 20 minutes to cut it after you score the mark with a straight edge and razor knife  and reset it in place. A little time spent for a long time reward.

If the door does not close or open on its own from being out of plumb or however it is not set properly, this is a little time spent in comparison to a resetting of the door. If it does open or close on its own and it is a problem, the door is really out of whack and could use a resetting. Usually a door, in my experiences , can be up to a 1/4" out of plumb in either direction and  the door leaf will stay where it is placed. Anything a 1/4" and more will move on its own, unless of course it is in the closed and latched position.

Comment: Done, this way, thanks. In the end, I found I was mistaken. The floor itself wasn't quite level. Not what I expected, but at least the door opens and the gap when closed isn't bad.

Answer (score 1):

If the floor is level as you say, and the door is square (probably is) check the hinge jamb and see if it's plumb / square to the floor.  If it isn't, you may be able to take the trim off, remove and replace the shims, and correct the problem without cutting the door.